# Azure B2C UPN authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have Azure AD in our tenant, being populated by our on premise AD.

We have an external application that is currently using forms based authentication (user accounts are stored in a DB). I'm looking at importing these user accounts into a new Azure B2C directory. I would like to retain the current login ID.

Very basic question: Can B2C users authenticate with both their B2C login ID as well as their UPN like they can in regular Azure AD?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) out?

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't help though.

I'll be bringing external user accounts into a B2C deployment. I'm wanting to know if I can have the current login ID for these external users set as their new UPN in B2C.

Comment: Actually, let me see if I can clarify this a little more.

If I import these external user accounts into a new B2C directory, they will all end up with a "username@something.onmicrosoft.com" login ID.

I cannot change the login ID for these users, so I was considering importing their current login ID as the new UPN on the username@something.onmicrosoft.com user.

This way the user can still authenticate with their original username, I simply don't need to advertise the @onmicrosoft login ID.

Answer (score 0):

If the user accounts in your database are simply usernames, you can import them as usernames ([using the graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)) and then allow users to sign in using usernames.